# Docker - invalid reference format

Tags: docker

I am trying to run Docker on Windows Powershell docker:
*invalid reference format.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              See 'docker run --help'.*
I think this is rather a Docker problem, not the particular tool issue.
My code looks like this: (all in one row)

```
docker run -v "YOUR_INPUT_DIR":"/input" -v "YOUR_OUTPUT_DIR:/output" google/deepvariant:"${BIN_VERSION}" /opt/deepvariant/bin/run_deepvariant --model_type=WES --ref=/input/hg38.fasta --reads=/input/file.bam --regions /input/file1.bed --output_vcf=/output/YOUR_OUTPUT_VCF --output_gvcf=/output/YOUR_OUTPUT_GVCF --call_variants_extra_args="use_openvino=true" --num_shards=$(nproc) --logging_dir=/output/logs
```

Thank you!

Comment: YOUR_INPUT_DIR and YOUR_OUTPUT_DIR must exist on the local filesystem

Comment: Type `echo` in front of docker in that command, run that to show the expanded variables, and show the output here.